# What's the best way of measuring elapsing time in POSIX with the milliseconds and microsecond accuracy?

Tags: c, linux, posix

I have some function `foo` and I want to get the elapsed time of it in the following format, for instance:

```
1 seconds 101 milliseeconds 31 microseconds
```

or

```
0 seconds 91 milliseeconds 101 microseconds
```

Now I use the following code for solving this problem:

```
static struct timeval t1, t2;
gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
foo();
gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
unsigned long long t = 1000 * (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) + (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) / 1000;
printf("elapsed time %llu ms\n", t);
```

I took this formula from the Net and not entirely understand it. Why I should 1000 multiplied by `(t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec)`?
What's the best way of measuring elapsing time in POSIX with the milliseconds and microsecond accuracy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Measuring time is a complex problem. Generally the best way is to use `clock_gettime()`.

It supports several clocks with different characteristics. Check [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/2/html/Realtime_Reference_Guide/sect-Realtime_Tuning_Guide-Timestamping-POSIX_Clocks.html) link for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The `tv_usec` field is the time elapsed in microseconds, and the `tv_sec` is the time elpased in seconds.

So multipliying `tv_sec` field by 1000 you convert seconds to milliseconds, and dividing `tv_usec` by 1000 you convert the microseconds to milliseconds.

I was going to suggest `clock_gettime()` but before I added that, **Let_Me_Be** posted an answer suggesting that.